# MYSQL Non cluster Index

Tags: mysql

I have create an index in mysql table like below.

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON mytable(Col1,Col2,Col3);
```

After creation, when I checked with manage index option in UI, its not fall under any category like **fulltext, unique, Key** that is its index type is empty. I have a doubt whether index created in this fashion will work ?

Comment: An index does not have to be unique or a key or fulltext.

Comment: Synax is correct

Comment: Thanks for confirm.